# mysql has two pid files

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I just finished re-building my (5.7) slave from a hot backup. When I issue

```
 systemctl start mysqld
```

it just "sat" there for over 20 minutes. It usually takes less than 10 seconds for the service to start. When I look at my server status, I see two mysql processes

```
mysql     1938     1  0 15:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
mysql     1940     1 99 15:25 ?        00:11:48 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
root      4024  3122  0 15:37 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
```

I stopped and restarted my service and there are two different PIDs showing up again

```
 [root@bi-db002-prd ~]# systemctl status mysqld -l
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Mon 2020-08-17 15:46:45 UTC; 45s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 7066 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Control: 7088 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           ├─7088 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
           └─7092 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Aug 17 15:46:45 bi-db002-prd systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
```

I have never seen that. Is there something incorrect with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is normal, mysql can so handle multiple requests, like apache webserver or firfox which do the same.

actually 2 is quite low, , if the number of requests/connections increases so will the number of proce4sses(till [max Connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) is reached). Two means that you and a free process are at the moment  connected